# Changes to javascript assets in BigCommerce Stencil theme not showing up in served pages

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

According to the the Stencil docs, we can make changes to javascript in assets/js:

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/customizing-javascript

However, when I make any changes (even like adding `console.log("Hello World");` as shown in the docs) the changes are not being served, ie, in this case the console is not showing any messages, and when I view the javascript source in the browser it does not show any of the changes I made.

I tried restarting stencil, using different browsers, resetting browser cache, etc. Anyone know why changes to assets/js are not being served from my dev server?

Comment: Try and check the source url for the JS that is being included using the Network tab in the inspector console. It seems like you are changing a different file that the one being served

Comment: Are you checking the source in your local environment or the live store?

Comment: I double-checked the URL, and I'm checking the right js file. This is all in my local environment. It looks like the js files are being packaged by webpack...the inspector in Chrome explicitly shows the assets/js directory as being under the webpack:// tree as opposed to localhost:3000 (when I look in the inspector's 'Sources' tab), and all of the js files have a comment appended at the end like:

Comment: (hit return too quickly)/** WEBPACK FOOTER **
 ** assets/js/theme/product.js
 **/

Comment: So it looks like webpack is not getting the edits I've made, but where else would it pull the files from?